# Installing Gentoo on windows7

Tags: installation, gentoo, boot

Hi this is gonna be a very basic and naive question to many of you, but please answer.

I am trying to install Gentoo from a live CD on my computer which already has windows 7 on it.

I have partitioned my hard disk into two C and E drive.

After booting from the live cd of Gentoo, I want to partition the disk using fdisk but without corrupting my windows.

the partitions 1 to 5 are full.

fdisk /dev/sda

how can I mark my boot partition, swap partition and root partition.

```
Device Boot   Start     END  Blocks  Id  System  
/dev/sda1      63     80324   40131  de   Dell utility 
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary 
/dev/sda2     81920    277664383   13791232  7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
/dev/sda3*  277664384  534284287    253309952 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
/dev/sda4   5344284288  976771071   221243392  f W95 Ext'd (LBA) 
/dev/sda5   534286336   976771071   221242368  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Kindly help
Thank you

Comment: How can partitions 1-7 be full if you only have 2 partitions? Please provide your current partition table.

Comment: Questions on ServerFault are expected to relate to the management of computer and network hardware/software in professional environments, within the scope of the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq] -- This seems to be a question about a personal system, which is better suited to [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) for future reference :-)

Answer (score 4):

Since this is 2012 and I hope you have kind of a decent computer in use, I have to ask: Why not to install Gentoo in a virtual machine? Just use [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org/), install Gentoo in it, and call it a day. Dual-booting should not be necessary nowadays unless you have some very special needs.

I'm a Linux user and my situation is reversed: I run my Windows XP / Windows 7 / Windows 8 in a VirtualBox and am perfectly happy with that.

Comment: Hence, the advice is to use GENTOO through Virtual Box.

Comment: While installing Gentoo through virtual box, I am being asked to select installation media (containing the set up program of the operating system. Now I have the bootable Gentoo CD... What shall I do... please answer

Comment: @Angelo, the [VirtualBox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#gui-createvm) is a very good place to start.